# Getting a List of Supported Devices for Your App

Tags: android, google-play

It would seem that Google has provided for us to post our application online and they provide for a nice overall list of [supported devices](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/1727131?hl=en&ref_topic=3365292).  This is just a list of all devices supported on the market however.

Within the Google Play Store, we as developers can choose to select filters on specific devices that we would like to support and [can exclude devices as desired](http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/about/distribution.html).  However, support is questioning how we can let customers know which devices are on that support list.

The only way that I can currently see how to check if a device is on the supported list (before someone actually purchases a device and physically checks), would be for us to internally open up the developer console and check for them.  This isn't really a manageable solution. I have to assume that there is somewhere that we as the developer can export the list of supported devices so that we can host it on a website somewhere and refer to it with a link from our website, or something similar.  And yet I can find nothing.  Has anyone had success in getting information from the Google Play Store for users?

**Updates:**

Simplistic means to try and retrieve this information have not proved fruitful.  A select-all over the list of devices on the web window covering the supported devices does not show which devices have been excluded.  It only shows devices that are supported by the restrictions from the manifest file.  And of course there will be new devices added to the list of devices each day, and they don't seem to have much of an order to them when they are added in to the list of supported devices for the application.  There doesn't seem to be much organization here.

Currently, we interact with specific external hardware for our application and we want to be sure that it works on families of devices before we support them, which is why it gets difficult to provide this list to customers.  There doesn't seem to be any export functionality or physical way to share the supported list of devices with the customers.

For instance, if we support the Samsung Galaxy families that we have done extensive tests upon, but some of those devices are not USB OTG compatible, then we would want to show exactly which Samsung Galaxy ones in a list are available to them (but it doesn't stop with Samsung only of course).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you need:

[List of supported devices](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/1727131?hl=en)

Note :
It was updated on  `2/18/2014` .

**EDIT :**

```
What would be needed is the list of devices that my application supports which is what gets filtered from the manifest file, as well as from exclusions that I have made within the store filters
```

AFAIK, there is no API provided by play store to get that list of devices because play-store applies filter on run time.

**Reference:**

Google Play uses the filter restrictions described below to determine whether to show your application to a user who is browsing or searching for applications from the Google Play app.

When determining whether to display your app, Google Play checks the device's hardware and software requirement, as well as it's carrier, location, and other characteristics. It then compares those against the restrictions and dependencies expressed by the application's manifest file and publishing details.

If the application is compatible with the device according to the filter rules, Google Play displays the application to the user. Otherwise, Google Play hides your application from search results and category browsing, even if a user specifically requests the app by clicking a deep link that points directly to the app's ID within Google Play.

checkout: [How Filters Work on Google Play](http://developer.android.com/google/play/filters.html)

Comment: No, I had already linked to that in my description above and spoke towards that.  What would be needed is the list of devices that my application supports which is what gets filtered from the manifest file, as well as from exclusions that I have made within the store filters.

Comment: @JaySnayder: AFAIK, there is no API provided by play store to get that list of devices.

Comment: This is the correct answer, yeah.  I contacted them via e-mail as well.  They do not support a white list of applicable devices in the Play Store as an exportable list.  It was suggested to them that I am willing to put in a feature request, but there doesn't seem to be a direct way to accomplish this.

Comment: @JaySnayder: That will be good if they provide such feature.when you put feature request,add reference to your question so that others can also  star your request.